# intel HD graphics: games only show part of the screen

Tags: intel-graphics

So here is my issue:
I am running Ubuntu 12.10 32bit with an Intel i5 card and integrated IronLake graphics (I think thats Intel HD 4000 although I'm not entirely sure).
The funny thing is that I have a few native Linux games, such as Humble Bundle 2 and 4, and seperate copies of Amnesia etc.
What's odd is that some of these games will show about a 3rd of the screen whilst others display normally.
Sounds strange I know but for instance, if I play 0AD, I get the full screen experience with no issues whatsoever.
However, Amnesia is a different story altogether, since there it seems as if the game is expecting my monitor to be much larger than it is and I see about a third of the top and a third of the left making the game unplayable.
Unfortunately, Amnesia is not the only one. One or two of the Humble Bundle games experience the same trouble.
It's gotten to a point where it's a hit-and-miss on whether a game works fine or not.

Does anyone have any advice?

And on a slightly related question, my Fn buttons don't work for brightness and gamma etc, anyone know how to get them to work? (since that's not my original question it's not too important).

Thanks
Arthur

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar problems with my games under linux like that. I also use intel graphics.

I never had to do anything special really to get them working. Try fiddling with the display settings of the games, running in windowed, then trying fullscreen on the next launch. Most of my issues seemed to fix themselves at that point.